# Can I show more than one button/option in teams using cards?

Tags: node.js, json, bots, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am trying to put 8 options in a card but I need to scroll to get other options horizontally. Is there it possible to make it available in a single card

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you can add only 6 actions directly in an adaptive card. If you want to send more than 6 buttons here are two things you could try:

1. Use ActionSets which would add 6 buttons in each set.In this way you can show 12 buttons in a card. Please try this out in the [AdaptiveCards Designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/).
2. You could try using [AdaptiveCard.ShowCard](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.ShowCard.html) action to show few buttons on a different card shown on click of a button.

Please let us know if you need any further assistance.